# How does one request for reputation for answers(Not upvoted or accepted) with working code when one spends good effort on it?

Tags: discussion

If I am a user with low reputation ( a few hundreds ) I try to answer questions that other experts generally don't pick. Because it involves some effort. An example is training machine learning data by tuning parameters repeatedly. This may sometimes involve lot of effort. I also learn during this process and understand this is a community effort.

So if such answers are neither upvoted or accepted I feel the effort is wasted.
What recourse does one have in such cases ? Just persist and answer many questions and hope for acceptance ?

I do see some users who mention in their profiles that they are authorized to award. I have to  bookmark such profiles.

Comment: Can you show such a profile? Afaik, noone except for the asker can accept an answer. And yes, it's demotivating when not getting feedback on your answers, but you can do almost nothing against it. Also note, that tuning parameters for machine learning does not really seem to be a programming problem and if I understand it correctly has zero long-term value (because parameters only fit to one dataset). Answering questions that are searched for by hundreds of people gives you upvotes for years, answering one that only helps the asker doesn't.

Comment: Why is such effort wasted? If your answer is good and helpful, you *helped people* and future visitors that have the ability to vote on your answer may well vote it up. *However*, if reputation is your primary motivation for posting in the first place, be prepared to be disappointed.

Comment: And **all** users are 'authorized to reward'. Please don't select on users that claim they have some special authorisation, there is none and that's *not the point of this site*. Focus on good questions you know you can answer well.

Comment: Should have bookmarked that. But I've seen comments from a user with high reputation offering to award 50+ to another asker who answered his own question if he accepts it. I thought some users have that privilege.

Comment: Oh, you mean [bounties](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties). Yes, they can be awarded starting from 75 reputation. But I wouldn't expect you to get a bounty for answering a question that doesn't help a lot of people (unless given by the asker).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Well if people *aren't* upvoting or accepting any of their answers then it's a sign that perhaps their answers *aren't* being helpful.  Maybe it's because the answers just aren't good answers, maybe it's because the topics are so obscure people just don't have that problem and so can't be helped by the answers.  Or maybe something else.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You don't.**

Everyone (above [75 reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/set-bounties)) has the exact same ability to reward other users, i.e. using upvotes and bounties.

You shouldn't go asking people to reward you - they will do so if they run into your answer and find it useful.

You could **edit the question** if you feel there's room for improvement. A question with a more meaningful title, more appropriate tags and that's generally easier to find for others with the same problem should draw more attention to itself and thus also to any answers to it.

You could **upvote the question** if you feel it's a useful question. This could also increase its visibility on the site (albeit marginally, in most cases), and thus bring more attention to your answer.

You could **add a bounty to the question** you answered, to draw more attention to it, but there's no guarantee that this will work and you may just suffer a loss - the bounty reputation is automatically "lost" (if you view it that way) because you wouldn't be able to award this bounty to your own answer.

If your primary motivator to answering such questions is reputation, you may find that to be a frustrating experience, because you often won't get any for answering. Reputation should, at most, be a nice little added bonus.

Comment: I think this is what I meant."You can award a bounty on an answer without accepting it." Yes. Your point about editing or upvoting the question which I answered to exhibit it is an interesting suggestion.

Answer (score 6):

Don't answer just because you want the points. You should answer because you already want to help people. The reputation is a secondary incentive at best. You shouldn't rely on it being your primary motivation.

Even if your post gets no votes at first, if it's a good and helpful answer, it may accumulate upvotes down the line still.

Everyone with over 15 reputation is "authorized to reward answers" by being able to upvote them.